# clipping a rectangle with semicircle shape

Tags: css, css-shapes, clip-path

I'm trying to build this indicator and as you can see it has rectangles with a small rounded portion clipped off. One of the requirements is that you should be able to see the strips "behind" the indicator so I can't just add another slightly bigger circle that sits behind the existing grey circle to achieve this effect.

I tried looking into `clip-path: clip(...)` but I can't make sense of all the values in the data/path string.

[image: indicator]

Comment: Is the whole thing one element or multiple elements? you need to see the HTML of your indicator

Comment: The approach I took was to make the circle the main element and the rectangles are pseudo `::before` and `::after` elements but I'm building it from scratch so I'm open to any suggested methods